# c# .net4 VisualStyles is there a way to make a forms controls to look as they do on Vista/win7 under XP?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Hi 
   I have a form that uses checkbox with the appearance set to button and it works well and looks good on Win7 but on XP it doesn't, you cannot tell if they are up or down...

so can I make the form look as it does on W7 regardless of which OS its running on?

I have tried  this.EnableVisualStyles = true; and setting it to false makes the form look crap in Win 7...

cheers

Comment: I take it that you are using classic Windows Forms and not WPF? WPF can render any way you like, but has a steep learning curve.

Comment: Hi Yes Classic windows forms, I don't want to spend the time redoing it in WPF, yet!

Comment: CheckBox doesn't use Windows to render itself.  I just checked, it looks fine on my XP machine.  Flat when pressed, 3D edges when not.  Post a screenshot and copy/paste the code from the Designer.cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. EnableVisualStyle only enables the OS-specific rendering (that is, non "classic" rendering). The buttons are always rendered OS-specific.

If you want OS-independent rendering, you have to use a control libary like Infragistics or Nevron. But I don't think this is a good idea anyway. Your application should look like it is integrated in the os theme in my opinion.